# Why getPackage().getSpecificationVersion() return null in command line

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I wrote a program to  get the version number of a package. And it worked well in Intellij. But when I ran this jar file in command line, the return value was null.

My maven project

```
  <groupId>com.client.version</groupId>
  <artifactId>version-specification</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Build-Number>${project.version}</Build-Number>
              <Timestamp>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</Timestamp>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This project contains only one class: get version number

```
package com.client.version;

public class ClientVersion {
     public ClientVersion() {
     }

public static String getCurrentVersion() {
    return ClientVersion.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion();
    }
}
```

I created another project

```
  <groupId>com.client.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-version</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.client.version</groupId>
    <artifactId>version-specification</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.3</version>
     <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and called `getCurrentVersion`method.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ClientVersion.getCurrentVersion());
    }
}
```

When I ran this program in IntelliJ, the output was `1.0`. 
But when I packaged a jar file and ran this main method in command line
`java -cp target/test-version-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar test.test`, the output is `null`, why ?.

Answer (score 0):

That happens due to classloader. Intellij runs everything in **non** packaged state. In the other case you packaged file, and then want to get some info without classpath, so you get null.